# Como usar los mensajes de HttpStatus

Tags: java, spring, jpa

¿Cómo usar los mensajes de HttpStatus ?

Por ejemplo, tengo este controller y lo que hago es mandar `HttpStatus.OK`, eso para el caso del exito pero, ¿y si falla que debo hacer?

```
@PostMapping("/createMeet")
    public ResponseEntity<Meet> createMeet(@RequestParam("user") Long idUser,@RequestBody Meet meet ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Meet>(meetService.createMeet(idUser, meet), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring otorga un mecanismo para la gestión de excepciones mediante la etiqueta `@ControllerAdvice` que se puede utilizar en una clase para usarla a modo de interceptor http, de forma que cada excepción que tu definas va a parar a este clase y puedes modificar la respuesta que decidas mandar en caso de excepción así como el ["HTTP status code"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP). Vamos a ver todo el proceso, lo primero es tener un controlador con nuestro endpoint:

```
@RestController()
public class MyAwesomeCoffeeController {

    @Autowired 
    private CoffeeService coffeeService;

    @GetMapping(value = '/{idCoffee}')
    public CoffeeResponse getCoffeeInfo(@PathVariable('idCoffee') String idCoffee) {
        coffeeService.getCoffeeById(idCoffee);
    }
}
```

Esta clase es el controlador, para simplificar el código no hemos añadido la inyección del service  que define el método getCoffee que corresponde a la URI:

```
Http.GET www.miurlfavorita.com/coffee/{id}
```

Una cosa importante es que el controlador **no tiene ningún tipo de lógica** ya que esta no es su función, su función es redireccionar las peticiones HTTP recibidas por el servidor al servicio correspondiente que se encarga de realizar la lógica necesaria, incluida la gestión de excepciones. Siguiendo nuestro ejemplo:

```
@Service()
public class MyAwesomeCoffeeService(){

    public CoffeeResponse getCoffeeById(String idCoffee){
        ...look for coffee info at a repository...
    }
}
```

Para simplificar, hemos quitado la lógica de acceso a los datos del servicio pero hay que tener en cuenta la separación de responsabilidades (llamar a un repositorio para buscar los datos). Ahora bien, volviendo a la pregunta original, necesito poder mandar respuestas en caso de error ya que mi código actual solo va a mandar por defecto un 200OK o un 500INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR en caso de fallo de mi código. Para esto, Spring pone a tu disposición la etiqueta @ControllerAdvicer y hay diversas cosas que puedes hacer con esto, vamos a ver un ejemplo muy simple, creamos nuestro manejador de excepciones:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Log
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    public static final String INTERNAL_ERROR_CUSTOM_MESSAGE = '... whatever internal error happened ...'

    /**
     * this method catches every exception to send a custom error json response
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception) //checkForEveryException
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason = "Error")
    public void everyException(Exception e) {
        log.info(INTERNAL_ERROR_CUSTOM_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Este exception handler es llamado en cada petición HTTP cuando se lanza una excepción y busca si hay un método que se active con esa excepción (la que está definida en `@ExceptionHandler`), en nuestro ejemplo, hemos puesto Exception que corresponde básicamente a cualquier error de nuestra aplicación, esto puede ser útil si queremos modificar la respuesta general de error para cualquier excepción, podemos modificar el mensaje de error, status code, definir un json de error diferente al genérico... Esta capa se encarga del manejo de excepciones en los controladores y nada más.

Pero en nuestro caso, podemos querer añadir una nueva excepción que corresponda a un código http distinto, por ejemplo, en nuestro caso podemos solicitar un café con un id que no existe en la base de datos y devolver una respuesta de error con un código 404NOT_FOUND. Para esto tenemos que lanzar una excepción específica en nuestro servicio (SIEMPRE en un servicio que es el encargado de la lógica de nuestra aplicación). En nuestro caso, al ser un "not found", podemos crear una Excepción EntityNotFoundException():

```
/**
* this exception is used to throw an exception if no data is found at DDBB
*/
public class EntityNotFoundException extends Exception {

    EntityNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
 }
```

Bien, ahora que tenemos nuestra excepción custom (una excepción que poder lanzar cuando no hay café en la base de datos), tenemos que mapear esta excepción a una respuesta HTTP 404, para ello añadimos el correspondiente método al exception handler que hemos creado previamente:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Log
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    public static final String INTERNAL_ERROR_CUSTOM_MESSAGE = '... whatever internal error happened ...';

    /**
     * this method catches every exception to send a custom error json response
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception) //checkForEveryException
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason = "Error")
    public void everyException(Exception e) {
        log.info(INTERNAL_ERROR_CUSTOM_MESSAGE);
    }

   /**
     * this method only catches our EntityNotFoundException
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "No coffee found")
    public void everyException(EntityNotFoundException e) {
        log.info(e.message);
    }
}
```

Ahora nuestras peticiones http tienen dos posibles respuestas de error, el 500 genérico que hemos definido previamente o el 404 que hemos definido en el segundo método. Para que nuestro servidor mande este 404, simplemente tenemos que lanzar la EntityNotFoundException en nuestro servicio cuando lo consideremos necesario, por ejemplo:

```
@Service()
public class MyAwesomeCoffeeService(){

    public CoffeeResponse getCoffeeById(String idCoffee){
        Coffee coffee = coffeeRepository.findByIdCoffee(idCoffee);
        if(coffee == null){
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("No coffee with that id");
        }
    }
}
```

Y con esto estaría nuestro flujo completo respetando por completo la separación de responsabilidades. Ojo que al lanzar la excepción se puede mandar un mensaje como parámetro que es lo que se está añadiendo al log en el controlador de excepciones, puedes usar esto para mandar información al exception handler que puedas necesitar para gestionar el error.

Answer (score 2):

Para el caso de tener que responder otros status (400, 404, 500, etc) tendrías que hacer un manejo de excepciones en el controller, recordemos que el status 200 es cuando todo sale como se esperaba.

Pero, ¿de donde salen esos errores? bueno, serán definidos en el BO (@Service) de tu aplicación por vos mismo, según la lógica planteada para el desarrollo de tu aplicación.

Aqui un ejemplo:

Service

```
@Autowired
public ContactsBo(ContactsRepository contactsRepository) {
    this.contactsRepository = contactsRepository;
}

public List<Contact> returnAll() {
    if (!this.contactsRepository.findAll().isEmpty()) {
        return this.contactsRepository.findAll();
    }
    throw new NoContactsFoundException();
}

public List<Contact> returnByName(String name) {
    if (!this.contactsRepository.findContactByName(name).isEmpty()) {
        return this.contactsRepository.findContactByName(name);
    }
    throw new NoContactsFoundException();
}
```

Podes ver como en caso de no encontrar ningún contacto en la base de datos voy a retornar una exception específica (hecha por mi para mi caso particular) la cual sera cacheada en el controller y tratada con un status 404 NOT FOUND.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<ContactsResponse> contacts() {
    try {
        LOGGER.info(START_RETURN_ALL, Contact.class);
        List<Contact> contacts = this.bo.returnAll();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ContactsResponse(contacts));
    } catch (NoContactsFoundException ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ERROR_CONTACTS_BY_NAME, ex);
        return ResponseEntity.status((HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)).body(null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ERROR_RETURN_ALL, ex);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: En ningún caso se debe añadir lógica en los controladores como tienes en tu ejemplo, no es una respuesta adecuada ya que rompe con el principio de separación de responsabilidades. Para esto Spring te da mecanismos para poder crear un manejador de excepciones

Comment: No hay ninguna lógica en el Controller, solo un cacheo de excepciones. Toda la lógica se encuentra en mi BO.

Comment: poner un catch en un controller ya supone lógica, estoy escribiendo una respuesta para que veas como separar esos if en su correspondiente capa, un saludo!

Comment: además de que esto te sirve si solo quieres modificar el http code pero qué pasa si quieres mandar un json custom de error junto al 404 por ejemplo? tendrías que añadir más lógica todavía, además de que si tienes muchos métodos que devuelvan un 404 vas a llevar de catch todos tus controladores mientras que con el exception handler solo pones esa lógica en un sitio una vez y todos los métodos del controlador pasan por ahí, te invito a que leas la respuesta que he añadido por si te resulta útil, saludos!

Comment: La verdad es que no conocia esa funcionalidad Blazerg, agradezco la dedicación, la voy a empezar a implementar. Saludos